# Could gravitational waves be cosmologicaly 'redshifted'?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, gravitational-waves, estimation, redshift

Is it posible that gravitational waves detected here on Earth could be cosmologicaly 'redshifted'? So, at emission they had higher frequency then after reaching Earth?